# How can I show sales for jan, feb march april.... on the same statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to make a report that will show sales side by side but I can only get one month per sheet this is what I currently have.

```
select c.[AR CUST Customer ID],c.[AR CUST Name], sum([AR SALE Subtotal]) as Jan_2013_Sales
from [AR Customer] c
 join [AR Sales] s
  on c.[AR CUST Customer ID]=s.[AR SALE Customer ID]
where [AR SALE Date] >= '1-01-2013' and [AR SALE Date] < '2-01-2013' and [AR SALE Document Type] like 'invoice'
group by c.[AR CUST Customer ID],c.[AR CUST Name]
order by [AR CUST Customer ID]
```

Currently this is the output that I get:

```
AR Cust Customer ID   |   AR Cust Name  |   Jan_2013_Sales

040891                |    Dans         |      268.8

041473                |    Dicks        |       2846.74
```

Which is fine but I would like to be able to from the same Query be able to pull:

```
AR Cust Customer ID   |   AR Cust Name  |   Jan_2013_Sales |  Feb_2013_Sales

040891                |    Dans         |       268.8      |     354.54

041473                |    Dicks        |       2846.74    |     1564.53
```

Comment: sounds like you want a `pivot table`. Can you add your RDBMS type to your question? Are you in sql server, postgres, mysql, access, db2, sybase...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know exactly what months you want to run this report for, you can do it this way...

```
select c.[AR CUST Customer ID],c.[AR CUST Name], jan.sumJan, feb.sumfeb, march.sumMarch
from [AR Customer] c
 left join (select [AR SALE Customer ID], sum([AR SALE Subtotal]) as sumJan from [AR Sales]
        where [AR SALE Date] >= '1-01-2013' and [AR SALE Date] < '2-01-2013' and [AR SALE     Document Type] like 'invoice'
        group by [AR SALE Customer ID]) jan on jan.[AR SALE Customer ID] = c.[AR CUST Customer ID]
 left join (select [AR SALE Customer ID], sum([AR SALE Subtotal]) as sumFeb from [AR Sales]
        where [AR SALE Date] >= '2-01-2013' and [AR SALE Date] < '3-01-2013' and [AR SALE     Document Type] like 'invoice'
        group by [AR SALE Customer ID]) Feb on Feb.[AR SALE Customer ID] = c.[AR CUST Customer ID]
 left join (select [AR SALE Customer ID], sum([AR SALE Subtotal]) as sumMarch from [AR Sales]
        where [AR SALE Date] >= '3-01-2013' and [AR SALE Date] < '4-01-2013' and [AR SALE     Document Type] like 'invoice'
        group by [AR SALE Customer ID]) March on March.[AR SALE Customer ID] = c.[AR CUST Customer ID]
order by [AR CUST Customer ID]
```

otherwise, you need a pivot table and here's an [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/500811/Simple-Way-To-Use-Pivot-In-SQL-Query) on codeProject.com

Answer (score 0):

You have to use something like IF or CASE statement for each month in SELECT STATEMENT

```
 SUM (IF( (AR SALE DATE >= 'START DATE January ' AND AR SALE DATE <= 'END DATE Jan '),AR SALE Subtotal, 0) as 'Jan SALE' ,  SUM (IF( (AR SALE DATE  >= 'START DATE FEB ' AND AR SALE DATE <= 'END DATE FEB '),AR SALE Subtotal, 0) as 'FEB SALE'
```

Remove the where clause. 
 if you have fiddle date it will help to write entire query.